# Search for specific keyword or regex pattern on git

Tags: regex, git, commit

How do you search through all commit messages in a git repository for a specific keyword or regex pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I am using perl and some linux tools in following way (this finds JIRA issues from projects DEDU, NCRM, MAPI, AI).

```
git log --oneline | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while m/(DEDU-\d+|NCRM-\d+|MAPI-\d+|AI-\d+)+/g' |  sort -r | uniq
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, but when I try running this command on my system, I get the following error: "The system cannot find the path specified."
How this works if we are using Strawberry Perl?

Comment: I am not familiar with Strawberry Perl at all but i guess all you need to do is add perl to your path. Maybe this will help http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm